# Extract from string delimited by one or more commas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to extract text after the first comma and potentially the remaining commas.

My text is addresses and some have lot numbers, units numbers ... I don't need.
I compare my addresses to a database with a specific format.

For example: *37 neptune Street, REVESBY NSW 2212*

The formula:

```
=RIGHT(B2,FIND(",",B2,1)-1)
```

returns *REVESBY NSW 2212*. This is what I want.

If I have *LADY GOWRIE CHILD CARE CENTRE, Ground Floor 1, 16 Spears Drive, DUBBO NSW 2830*.
I get *Spears Drive, DUBBO NSW 2830*.
The formula is giving me everything to right of the second comma.

I want to extract data separately before each comma. So I can have *Street Number*, *Street Name*, *suburb*, *Post Code*.

My data for every cell is a bit different.

Comment: Just use the [Text to Columns Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) to split text by comma into columns.

Comment: To return just the `suburb, postcode`, you should be extracting the data after the last comma.  You can use:  `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),99))` for that.  But to split the address into all the relevant segments, you will need to split on the comma, and then apply logic to each segment to determine whether it is a `Street Number`, `Street Name`, etc.  That is probably best done using VBA, since you seem to have much variation in your data. You may also need a lookup table to validate some of the data.

Answer (score 1):

So, just to show a method using functions while Peh shows a better method:

[image]

The trim() removes leading or trailing spaces,
The +1 is to not pick up the comma after the find() gets its position.

By using find() to drive a second find() you can split out all of the parts, but it gets cumbersome... Left for you to try...